# What is exactly the difference between "gaze" and "stare"?

Tags: meaning

According to dictionaries, they both mean "to look steadily at somebody / something".

Answer (score 5):

This has been asked before on ELU, where [what I think is the best answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/95296/2637) says...

> **Stare** - look for a long time with the eyes wide open, especially when surprised, frightened or thinking
>
> **Gaze** - look at something or someone for a long time, especially in surprise, admiration or *because you are thinking about something else*.

I wouldn't make too much of that italicised distinction though. Note these usage figures...

> [gazed absent-mindedly](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22gazed%20absent-mindedly%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) *(2220 hits in Google Books)*
> [stared absent-mindedly](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22gazed%20absent-mindedly%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22stared%20absent-mindedly%22&oq=%22stared%20absent-mindedly%22&gs_l=serp.3...2785.6478.0.6829.11.11.0.0.0.2.346.1501.5j4j1j1.11.0...0.0...1c.1.15.psy-ab.8Z8GygPv1QI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.ZG4&fp=410395c6aafad6cc&biw=1292&bih=916) *(2480 hits)*

...where I doubt it would make any real difference if every single usage were reversed.

---

*However*, there's at least one context where idiomatically the two words are not at all interchangeable. That's when *stare* is used to mean [gawp,](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=gawp&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=oKWrUYuYBo7s0gW71YCADQ&ved=0CC4QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.d2k&fp=aea4b66ba6c263be&biw=1292&bih=916) [rubberneck](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rubberneck), [goggle](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/goggles) *(stare openly in a stupid or rude manner)*.

Suppose, for example, in the supermarket with your child, you're behind wheelchair-bound paraplegic [Stephen Hawking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Hawking) in the checkout queue. Your child may well be fascinated, but what *you* say is...

> [*Don't **stare!** [at him]*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22don%27t%20stare%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22don%27t%20stare%20at%20him%22&oq=%22don%27t%20stare%20at%20him%22&gs_l=serp.3...21173.25253.0.25790.11.9.2.0.0.1.136.736.8j1.9.0...0.0...1c.1.15.psy-ab.3_EmCkWe2ag&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.d2k&fp=410395c6aafad6cc&biw=1292&bih=916) (in such contexts, no-one ever says [*Don't gaze!*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22don%27t%20stare%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22don%27t%20gaze%20at%20him%22&oq=%22don%27t%20gaze%20at%20him%22&gs_l=serp.3...3905.5937.1.6168.9.9.0.0.0.0.143.788.8j1.9.0...0.0...1c.1.15.psy-ab.DC_aalkGhpE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.d2k&fp=410395c6aafad6cc&biw=1292&bih=916)).

Comment: So, can we say that "stare" implies negative connotation?

Comment: @Dragon Buster: That's not how I'd put it. Per the first part of the answer as copied from ELU, for most purposes *stare/gaze* are synonyms. Using *stare* doesn't have negative connotations in and of itself - it's just that if what you're saying is obviously negative anyway, you would normally use *stare* rather than *gaze*. Conversely, if you wanted to convey "serenely neutral detachment", you'd tend to use *gaze* rather than stare, but that tendency isn't so strong.

Comment: Here's an instance where "gaze" is appropriate but "stare" is not: gazing at the stars (stargazing). But that might have become a set phrase only because "starstaring" looks really weird.

Comment: @Brian: Four centuries ago (when OE first records the usage) I doubt anyone thought ***star-staring** looks "weird" - let's use **star-gazing** instead*. The reason one looks "normal" to you today, and the other looks "weird" is simply because you're *familiar* with the version that actually became established. But I have to say using it as a full verb *("He star-gazed last night")* still sounds really weird to me. I can only really feel comfortable with it as a gerund.

Comment: It doesn't sound weird, it just looks weird. My eye wants to see it as star-star +ing.  i agree with you about the gerund; it's not conjugatable.

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from an old tome, distinction between words by john trusler.
"Both stare and gaze means to fix both eyes upon an object, intently, earnestly with wonder. Staring implies looking with wonder and impudence; gazing with wonderband respect." A rude fellow will stare one in the face but a lover gazes upon his girlfriend with affection and admiration.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELL. Please take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Can you link to, or at least better identify, your reference?

Comment: **John Trusler** instead of _john trusler_.

Comment: You might also like to edit to expand on what this adds to the existing answer.